# Does feature stappling is allowed in custom web templates for SharePoint 2010?

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

Does feature stappling is allowed in custom web templates  for SharePoint 2010?If not , I guess I need to use the feature receiver to activate features?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[SharePoint 2010 and web templates - Feature stapling](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vesku/archive/2010/10/14/sharepoint-2010-and-web-templates.aspx#stapling)

> Primary purpose of the feature
>   stapling is to extend and customize
>   existing site definitions. Usually
>   these are used to provide some custom
>   functionalities for the out of the box
>   site definitions, but **technique is
>   definitely available also for the
>   custom site definitions**.